# How can I get the current computer´s domain via asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

In .NET 4.7.2 I can get the current computer domain

```
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;

using (var lDomain = Domain.GetComputerDomain())
{
    [...]
}
```

How can I get the current computer´s domain via asp.net core?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use [IPGlobalProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties?view=netcore-3.1)
to get your current domain.

It provides information about the network connectivity of the local computer.

```
      var re =   System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on some searches, you should be able to install https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices and use that class.

In .NET Core these classes are not part of the framework, requiring you to install Nuget packages for them.